# how perform undo redo on canvas without losing previous color

Tags: android

Am not performing Undo/Redo operation canvas  in this code. When am use the array list for removing the postion then it not work and during changing the color of paint from color picker the previous drawing color has been also change. 
I am not understanding that how to perform UNDO/REDO for this.
So plz help

//This is main class

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView (mView = new MyView(this));

mPaint = new Paint();
mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
mPaint.setDither(true);
mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
mPaint.setStrokeWidth(4);

mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] { 1, 1, 1 },
                               0.4f, 6, 3.5f);

mBlur = new BlurMaskFilter(8, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);
```

}

//And  MyView class is

```
public class MyView extends View {

private static final float MINP = 0.25f;
private static final float MAXP = 0.75f;  
private Bitmap  mBitmap;
private Canvas  mCanvas;
private Path    mPath;
private Paint   mBitmapPaint;
ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>();
public MyView(Context c) 
{
super(c);

mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(320, 480, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
mPath = new Path();
mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
// mCanvas.setBackgroundResource(0xFFFFFFFF);
mCanvas.drawColor (0xFFFFFFFF);
paths.add(mPath);
}
public MyView (Context c, int color)
   {
   super(c);

     mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(320, 480, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
     mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
     mPath = new Path();
     mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
     mCanvas.drawColor (color);
     paths.add(mPath);
  }
@Override protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) 
 {
     super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
 }

 @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
  {
     canvas.drawColor(0xFF000000);

     canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
     for(Path p: paths)
      {
     canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
      }
    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
   }

   private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
      }
   }

   private void touch_up() {
       mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);  
       mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
       paths.add(mPath);
       mPath.reset();
     }

  @Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
       float x = event.getX();
       float y = event.getY();

     switch (event.getAction()) {
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
       }
       return true;
     }

    public void clear ()
     {
         Paint p = new Paint();
         p.setAntiAlias(true);
         p.setDither(true);
         p.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
         mCanvas.drawPaint (p);
      } 

   public void drawImage (int resourceId)
    {
         Bitmap _scratch = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resourceId);
         mCanvas.drawBitmap(_scratch, 0, 0, null);
    } 
    public void undo() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mCanvas.drawCircle(posX, posY, 100, mPaint);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", 1000).show();
        if (paths.size()>0) 
        { 
           undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size()-1));
           mView.invalidate();
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Undo", 1000).show();
         }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not", 1000).show();
        }
    }
          public void redo() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (undonePaths.size()>0) 
        { 
            paths.add(undonePaths.remove(undonePaths.size()-1)); 
            invalidate();
        } 
        else 
        {

        }

    }
   public void saveAsJpg (File f)
     {
        String fname = f.getAbsolutePath ();
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream (f);
        mBitmap.compress (CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, fos);                 
       } catch (Throwable ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace ();
       }      
     } // end saveAsJpg

   } // end MyView

   } // end class FingerPaint
```

Answer (score 3):

```
this working code .I test it on my own app and it is working very good.
May be it help u.Please comment on it.
            public class Main extends Activity implements OnColorChangedListener {
            //public static int selectedColor = Color.BLACK;
            public static ArrayList<Path> mMaindialog;
            // private ArrayList<Path> undonePaths;
            // public int selectedcolor;
            private static final String COLOR_PREFERENCE_KEY = "color";
            private FrameLayout relativelayout;
            static String sdpath,location;
            Boolean i;
            // Instance variables
            private Bitmap mBitmap=null;
            Bitmap bitmap;
            private Paint mPaint, mBitmapPaint, mPaint1;
            private MyView mView;
            ImageView idd;
            // private Path mPath;
            int slll = Color.BLACK;
            Bitmap map=ListView5.bMap;
            private Button ClearPaint, Colorpaint;
            Ghostdatabase gost;

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
                 idd=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                relativelayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);

                DisplayMetrics metrics = getBaseContext().getResources()
                        .getDisplayMetrics();
                int w = metrics.widthPixels;
                int h = metrics.heightPixels;

                System.out.println(" width " + w);
                System.out.println(" height " + h);



                mView = new MyView(this, w, h);
                mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

                mPaint = new Paint();
                mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
                mPaint.setDither(true);
                mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
                mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
                mPaint.setStrokeWidth(4);

                ClearPaint = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ne);
                ClearPaint.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // mBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                        // mPath.reset();
                        // mView.invalidate();

                        mView.onClickUndo();

                    }
                });
                Button save22 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
                save22.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        File cacheDir;
                        Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Photo", 500).show();
                        Bitmap icon;
                        relativelayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

                        icon = Bitmap.createBitmap(relativelayout.getDrawingCache());
                        Bitmap bitmap = icon;
                        relativelayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
                        // File mFile1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                        Date d = new Date();
                        String fileName = d.getTime() + "mg1.jpg";

                        File storagePath = (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
                        File dest = new File(storagePath + "/CityAppImages");

                        if (!dest.exists()) {
                            dest.mkdirs();

                        }

                        File mFile2 = new File(dest, fileName);
                        sdpath = mFile2.getAbsolutePath();

                        Log.d("qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq", "zzzzzzzz" + sdpath);
                        try {
                            FileOutputStream outStream;

                            outStream = new FileOutputStream(mFile2);

                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);

                            outStream.flush();

                            outStream.close();
                            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Photo Saved Sucessfully", 500)
                                    .show();
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {

                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Photo Not Saved Sucessfully",
                                    500).show();
                        }

                        gost = new Ghostdatabase(Main.this);
                        gost.open();

                        gost.insertTitle(sdpath);
                    }
                });

                Button view = (Button) findViewById(R.id.listtt);
                view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Intent ii = new Intent(Main.this, ListView5.class);
                        startActivity(ii);

                    }
                });

                Button Colorpaint = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Color);
                Colorpaint.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int color = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(
                                Main.this).getInt(COLOR_PREFERENCE_KEY, Color.WHITE);
                        // int _color = R.color.red;
                        new ColorPickerDialog(v.getContext(),
                                new OnColorChangedListener() {

                                    public void colorChanged(int color) {
                                        mPaint.setColor(color);

                                        slll = color;

                                        Log.i("TAG", "mpaint one" + mPaint);
                                    }
                                }, mPaint.getColor()).show();
                        Log.i("TAG", "mpaint two" + mPaint);
                    }
                });
                relativelayout.addView(mView);
            }



            // //////////******************* Pinting view
            // *******************///////////////////

            public class MyView extends View implements OnTouchListener {
                private Map<Path, Integer> colorsMap = new HashMap<Path, Integer>();
                private ArrayList<Path> mMaindialog = new ArrayList<Path>();
                private ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>();
                int colorPicked = slll;
                // Paint mPaint1;

                private Canvas mCanvas;
                private Path mPath;

                public MyView(Context c, int w, int h) {
                    super(c);
                    if(GlobalVariable.impath==1)
                    {
                        Log.d("","111111"+GlobalVariable.impath);
                        System.out.println(GlobalVariable.impath);
                        Intent ii = getIntent();
                         location = ii.getStringExtra("IMAGE");
                        // bitmap.recycle();
                         Log.d("","location"+location);
                         bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(location);
                         mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,300, 300,false);
                         Log.d("hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhssssssss","mBitmap"+mBitmap);
                         //mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                        // idd.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
                        Log.d("hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhssssssss","GlobalVariable.impath"+GlobalVariable.impath);
                    }
                    else if(GlobalVariable.impath==2){
                        //bitmap.recycle();
                        Log.d("","22222222222222222222222"+GlobalVariable.impath);
                        bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.base);
                        mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,100, 100, false);
                        //mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                        Log.d("hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhssssssss1111111","mBitmap"+mBitmap);
                    }



        //          
                    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
                    mPath = new Path();

                }

                @Override
                protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
                    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

                }

                @Override
                protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

                    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

                    for (Path p : mMaindialog) {
                        mPaint.setColor(colorsMap.get(p));
                        canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
                    }
                    mPaint.setColor(slll);
                    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
                }

                // //////************touching evants for painting**************///////
                private float mX, mY;
                private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 0;

                private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
                    mPath.reset();
                    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
                    mX = x;
                    mY = y;
                    undonePaths.clear();
                }

                private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
                    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
                    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
                    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
                        mX = x;
                        mY = y;
                    }
                }

                private void touch_up() {
                    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
                    // commit the path to our offscreen
                    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
                    // kill this so we don't double draw
                    mPath = new Path();
                    mPath.reset();
                    mMaindialog.add(mPath);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
                    float x = event.getX();
                    float y = event.getY();
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        // touch_start(x, y);
                        // invalidate();
                        undonePaths.clear();
                        mPath.reset();
                        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
                        mX = x;
                        mY = y;
                        invalidate();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        // touch_move(x, y);
                        // invalidate();
                        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
                        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
                        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
                            mX = x;
                            mY = y;
                        }
                        invalidate();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        // touch_up();
                        // invalidate();
                        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
                        mMaindialog.add(mPath);
                        colorsMap.put(mPath, slll);
                        mPath = new Path();
                        mPath.reset();
                        invalidate();
                        break;
                    }
                    return true;
                } // end of touch events for image

                private Paint createPen(int colorPicked) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mPaint1 = new Paint();
                    mPaint1.setColor(colorPicked);
                    mPaint1.setAntiAlias(true);
                    mPaint1.setDither(true);
                    mPaint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                    mPaint1.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
                    mPaint1.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
                    // mPaint1.setStrokeWidth(3);
                    return mPaint1;
                }

                public void onClickRedo() {
                    if (undonePaths.size() > 0) {
                        mMaindialog.add(undonePaths.remove(undonePaths.size() - 1));
                        mView.invalidate();

                    } else {

                    }
                    // toast the user
                }

                public void onClickUndo() {
                    if (mMaindialog.size() > 0) {
                        undonePaths.add(mView.mMaindialog.remove(mView.mMaindialog
                                .size() - 1));
                        mView.invalidate();
                    }

                    else {

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return false;
                }
            }// end MyView

            @Override
            public void colorChanged(int color) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit()
                        .putInt(COLOR_PREFERENCE_KEY, color).commit();
                slll = color;
            }



        }
```